# Не работает комбинация str.maketrans и translate

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь поменять буквы в строке на соответствующие им номера в алфавите.
Не понимаю почему не работает translate.
Плюс ко всему прочему `maketrans` выдаёт очень странную таблицу для перевода `tr`, в ней совершенно не фигурируют буквы.
Что я делаю не так?

```
import string


eg = ['test', 'abc', 'xyz', 'whyunotwork']
new = []
dic = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, map(str, range(1, 27))))
tr = str.maketrans(dic)

for word in eg:
    word1 = word.translate(dic)
    new.append(word1)

print(new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы не используете `tr`, используйте его:

```
word1 = word.translate(tr) # tr, а не dic
```

Вывод:

```
['2051920', '123', '242526', '238252114152023151811']
```